# Speed up this bash script

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have files containing data in a format like this

```
<Tag1>content  
<Tag2>optional tag content  
<Tag3>content

<Tag1>other content  
<Tag3>other content
```

Where each block of tags represents the data required to populate an object. Some tags are also optional.

Currently I am processing the data files with this code

```
#!/bin/bash
tag1=""
tag2=""
tag3=""

while read line; do

 if  [[ $line == '<Tag1>'* ]]
  then
   tag1=`echo $line | cut -c 6- | tr -d '\r'`
 elif  [[ $line == '<Tag2>'* ]]
  then
   tag2=`echo $line | cut -c 6- | tr -d '\r'`
 elif  [[ $line == '<Tag3>'* ]]
  then
   tag3=`echo $line | cut -c 6- | tr -d '\r'`
   #write new object to output file and reset tag variables
 fi

done <file.dat
```

where cut gets the data after the tag and tr removes any new lines following the data.

This code is very slow though especially when you have hundreds of files to process with thousands of lines.

Would there be a faster way to do this and also handle the optional tags (when not there just pass "") with something like awk?

EDIT:

Im using it to populate an sql table so I use the output to create INSERT statements:

```
echo "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('$tag1','$tag2','$tag3');" >> output.sql
```

2nd Edit

Given an input of

```
<Tag1>Some sample text including don't
<Tag2>http://google.com
<Tag3>$100
```

the ideal output would be INSERT INTO MyTable Values("Some sample text including don't", "http://google.com", "$100");

Obviously if I was going to use single quotes to pass in the values and not quotes I would have to double up on the apostrophes like in "don't" so that it doesn't escape the input early.

Comment: Yes, rewriting it in awk will make it at least an order of magnitude faster, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input so we can help you.

Comment: @Ed Have now edited to include output

Comment: @EdMorton sorry my latest edit should hopefully have answered your question

Comment: It's getting messy. Simply post 1 file of sample input and the associated output you want to get from that input. You show single quotes in your `echo` "output" but double quotes in your subsequent output - pick one and show us what you want done when that quote appears in your input (there is no "Obviously..."). Make sure your sample input/output includes multiple records since it sounds like your real input/output will include multiple records. Just make it as clear, simple and realistic as possible and include the cases you think could be problematic (e.g. quotes or `>` in the input).

Comment: @EdMorton Don't worry with a few edits I managed to get your awk script working, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question since you haven't shown the expected output but this MIGHT be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = ""
    FS = "\n"
    fmt = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(\047%s\047, \047%s\047, \047%s\047);\n"
}
{
    delete v
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        tag = val = $i
        gsub(/^<|>.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/^[^>]+>/,"",val)
        v[tag] = val
    }
    printf fmt, v["Tag1"], v["Tag2"], v["Tag3"]
}
```

Here's the kind of input file you should be asking us to test with as it contains some traditionally problematic characters and strings:

```
$ cat file
<Tag1>with 'single\' quotes
<Tag2>http://foo.com
<Tag3>trailing backslash\

<Tag1>With <some> "double\" quotes
<Tag3>with \1 backrefs & here
```

and here's the output the above script produces given that input:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('with 'single\' quotes', 'http://foo.com', 'trailing backslash\');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('With <some> "double\" quotes', '', 'with \1 backrefs & here');
```

If any of that is not what you want then edit your question to show that input (or similar) plus the output you DO want.

Answer (score 3):

An `awk` solution would probably be faster, but this Bash solution should be quicker than your original code :

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="^<Tag([1-3])>(.*)$"
while IFS= read -r line
do
 if
   [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
 then
   case ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} in
     1) tag1=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ;;
     2) tag2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ;;
     3) echo "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('$tag1','$tag2','${BASH_REMATCH[2]}');" >> output.sql 
        tag1= ; tag2= ;;
   esac
 fi
done <file.dat
```

Please note that all lines are matched with the same regular expression, the 1/2/3 is handled by the case statement.  Obviously, the above will be very sensitive to, say, whitespace inside tags or upper/lower case, so consider your actual data and make any required adjustment to the regular expression if you need it to tolerate variations.